# Android - Gson parsing error - Malformed Json Exception

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm trying mapping the next string resource into my own "Studies" POJO class using GSON.

```
<string name="b">
{
    "Id": 4,
    "IdUser": 1,
    "PathPics": "G:\\dariop\\SRC\\000.Pers\\007.Tomas Mosquera\\Estudios\\18-001_246",
    "Name": "18-001_246",
    "Description": "Estudio generado al seleccionar carpeta de imagenes",
    "Active": true,
    "Sincronizado": false,
    "DateUpd": "2018-04-25T08:34:09.607",
    "pics": [{
        "IdStudiesPic": 26,
        "IdStudies": 4,
        "Path": "C:\\DRS_Homologacion\\Studies\\18-001_246\\001_CA.jpg",
        "Name": "001_CA.jpg",
        "Sincronizada": false,
        "DateUpd": "2018-05-27T19:27:21.743",
        "Id": 26,
        "Active": false
    }, {
        "IdStudiesPic": 27,
        "IdStudies": 4,
        "Path": "C:\\DRS_Homologacion\\Studies\\18-001_246\\002_TA.jpg",
        "Name": "002_TA.jpg",
        "Sincronizada": false,
        "DateUpd": "2018-05-27T19:27:49.79",
        "Id": 27,
        "Active": false
    }],
    "paciente": {
        "Id": 246,
        "dni": 28095876,
        "Name": "Prueba 3",
        "Lastname": "Prueba 3",
        "Telephone": "11547658900",
        "Email": "prueba3@gmail.com",
        "Coment": "",
        "DateUpd": "2018-04-25T08:33:46",
        "Birthday": "1990-05-13T00:00:00",
        "GenderType": "M",
        "genero": null,
        "Active": true,
        "fototipo": {
            "Id": 2,
            "Fototipo": "II",
            "TonoPielColorOjos": "Piel clara y ojos azules",
            "ColorCabello": "Rubio",
            "QuemaduraSolar": "Habitualmente",
            "Bronceado": "Ligero, descamación",
            "Active": true
        },
        "IdFototipo": 2
    },
    "IdPatient": 246,
    "Imagen": null,
    "Lesiones": null,
    "NombrePaciente": null
}
</string>
```

using

```
    String b = getResources().getString(R.string.b);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Studies study = gson.fromJson(b, Studies.class);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 33 path $.PathPics
```

I know that the white space might be the problem here but I can't solve the issue (unfortunately modifying the string is not an option). Also the double \ may introduce some undesired behaviour.

Can you help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the JSON string can't be placed inside a `strings.xml`. You need to save the string to **raw** directory which is inside `res/raw`. Create a file inside the directory, for example: **myfile.json**. So the path will be `res/raw/myfile.json`. Then read open it inside your code with this:

```
// open the resource from raw file
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);
try {
  Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins, "UTF-8"));
  Writer writer = new StringWriter();
  int size;

  char[] buffer = new char[1024];
  // read the whole file to a writer.
  while ((size = reader.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, size);
  }

  // now we have the string
  String json = writer.toString();
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  // translate it to the object.
  Studies study = gson.fromJson(json, Studies.class);

  // Now you have the correct object translated from the json file.

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  // Error!! Do something here. Please don't ignore me.
}
```